# Inserting Image into Internal Memory 

Tags: android

I am trying to insert an image into the phone memory of an Android phone.  I am getting the following exceptions, although when I tried with the `EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` there was no problem, but if the SD card is not present, I want to write to phone memory.

Could any one please give me a solution for this? Thanks in advance.

#

MY CODE

#

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(2);

values.put(Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "My Bitmap");

values.put(Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);

//Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);

OutputStream outStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);

b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, outStream);

outStream.close();

###################################
11-03 20:02:48.526: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(167): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Writing to internal storage is not supported.
11-03 20:02:48.526: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(167):     at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.generateFileName(MediaProvider.java:1646)
11-03 20:02:48.526: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(167):     at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.ensureFile(MediaProvider.java:1337)
11-03 20:02:48.526: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(167):     at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insertInternal(MediaProvider.java:1413)
11-03 20:02:48.526: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(167):     at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insert(MediaProvider.java:1381)
11-03 20:02:48.526: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(167):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:150)
11-03 20:02:48.526: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(167):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:140)
11-03 20:02:48.526: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(167):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:287)
11-03 20:02:48.526: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(167):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you found solution ?

Answer (score 0):

By design, you do not have write permission to the internal media directory (To any space in internal memory for that matter except your own space). If you check what `Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.getPath()` returns you will see that it is not a location within your application's directory.

If you want to save your Bitmap to internal memory, use the following code:

```
String filename = "My Bitmap.jpg";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
    outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Read more here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html